# Jelastic - How to fix bash_profile with invalid characters entered when creating environment variables?

Tags: linux, server, jelastic

In advance, I apologize for my English.
It was while researching how to solve the problem that I discovered Jelastic's recommendations for creating environment variables. Without this knowledge, I created variables like I create in linux, where in case of error, I can edit the bash_profile file easily. Which doesn't happen on Jelastic servers.
The error is that I inserted incorrect lines when declaring environment variables in the bash_profile. These lines generated warnings as shown in the print. I did a lot of research and couldn't figure out how to fix it. can you help me?

The line that caused the problem was:
`export BACKUP_DELETE_SCHEDULE=0 0 * * 1-5`.
Entered with command in terminal
`echo "export BACKUP_DELETE_SCHEDULE=0 0 * * 1-5" >> ~/.bash_profile`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LFMP.png)

Comment: Please add the full .bash_profile (or at least the lines you believe to be causing the problem) to your question.

Comment: Hi, @Damien - Layershift  . I added the line of code causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. What went wrong?

```
export BACKUP_DELETE_SCHEDULE=0 0 * * 1-5
```

Is interpreted as something like:

```
export BACKUP_DELETE_SCHEDULE=0
export 0
export *
export *
export 1-5
```

To put all of that into the variable you must wrap it in quotation marks:

```
export BACKUP_DELETE_SCHEDULE="0 0 * * 1-5"
```

So appending to the existing `~/.bash_profile` file would be like this:

```
echo 'export BACKUP_DELETE_SCHEDULE="0 0 * * 1-5"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

## 2. How to fix it

On Jelastic nodes, this file is deliberately not editable (only append-able):

```
$ lsattr .bash_profile
-----a-------e-- .bash_profile
```

Meaning:

- A file with the 'a' attribute set can only be opened in append mode for writing.
- The 'e' attribute indicates that the file is using extents for mapping the blocks on disk.

Therefore you need to either:

- delete the node (and create a new one)
- contact your hosting provider's support team for assistance to delete the problem line(s) from your `.bash_profile`

Obviously the preferred option depends if you need the data on this node or not...

## 3. How to avoid it in future

Besides not making the mistake (see #1), the [Jelastic documentation describes another way](https://docs.jelastic.com/custom-environment-variables/#set-up-environment-variables-via-shell-configs) - they suggest to create a `~/.bashrc` file (which you would have full permissions to edit, in case of any mistakes) which Jelastic already automatically `source` within `~/.bash_profile`.

Please also note the differences regarding when `.bash_profile` is used vs. `.bashrc`:

> - `~/.bash_profile` is executed only upon login via console
> - `~/.bashrc` is executed for each new bash instance